# Hyperledger fabric network(1.1.0) cannot create a channel between a peer and an orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to config a hyperledger fabric network on aws.
I have 3 aws ubuntu instances and each is fabric-ca, fabric-orderer, fabric-peer latest docker image.

First, I started up my CA server with "start -b" command. I checked one identity is registered in CA server db. 
After that, I started up my orderer server. After that enrolled CA registered identity on the orderer server and registered and enrolled orderer identity using `fabric-ca-client` bin. Finally I created genesis block using `configtxgen` bin.

The Problem is here.

I started up a peer and proceeded same steps mentioned above and created an identity type peer. After that I created admincerts directory and put a cert.pem in a ca signcerts directory. I though this certification file describes an identity created by CA.

But when I tried to create a channel to orderer, it says `error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining` .

How can I make `administrator` certification for a peer to create a channel?

Comment: Additionanlly I uses admin identity which is created by fabric-ca-server bootstrap identity. I check all pem characters whether it doesnt't match to each other.. but it's same.

Answer (score 1):

channel creation has many error prone areas

1). It could be that you are passing a wrong `mspID`.
2) Detailed Explanation reg Admin keys

```
NodeJS Logs: [2018–10–04 12:19:28.548] [DEBUG] Create-Channel — response ::{“status”:”BAD_REQUEST”,”info”:”error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining”}
[2018–10–04 12:19:28.548] [ERROR] Create-Channel —
```

!!!!!!!!! Failed to create the channel ‘public’ !!!!!!!!!

Orderer Logs: reg channel creation error

```
2018–10–04 08:19:28.617 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 132 [channel: public] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 10.255.0.2:57714 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

Reason: transaction is not signed with admin key

Solution: To create a channel we need admin credentials such as private key & public certificate(Ex: x.509)

Comment: can you develop the second point about admin to create channel ?